# Mysql - Table updated through a query. On duplicate key update not working

Tags: mysql, insert

The task is to keep "mg_brands" table updated with values coming from query on another two tables.

Tables are:

```
mg_brands | mg_term_taxonomy  |mg_terms
----------|-------------------|--------------
term_id   | term_taxonomy_id  |term_id
name      | term_id           |name
          | taxonomies        |
```

Basically, it works in this way:
mg_terms contain records having different categories identified by the "field mg_term_taxonomy.taxonomies".

I would like to extract records having taxonomy "brand" and transfer that data into "mg_brands". The query should be capable of checking existing records updating them or insert new ones if not exist.

For that I am using the below reported query but it create new records, duplicating them instead of doing what I already said.

```
INSERT into mg_brands

    SELECT mg_terms.term_id,  mg_terms.name
    FROM mg_terms
    JOIN mg_term_taxonomy
    ON mg_term_taxonomy.term_id=mg_terms.term_id
    WHERE mg_term_taxonomy.taxonomy="product_brand"

    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    mg_brands.term_id = mg_terms.term_id,
    mg_brands.name= mg_terms.name
```

Any suggestion why the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not doing its work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "is not doing its work?" Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi, I mean that instead of checking if the record exists and eventually update the fields, the query add records every time I launch it. I suppose it depends from the bad coding on that part.

Comment: A question about `ON DUPLICATE KEY` that doesn't include the `KEY`s that the (key)word `KEY` in that command is referring to (your indexes on that table) is missing a very important part. So please add them (e.g. as output of `show create table mg_brands`).

Comment: @Solarflare, the key is the term_id in the mg_brands. At this point I have no idea how to implement the function I need. Any suggestion?

Comment: Then as @Solarflare says, you have a problem with your KEY. Are tyou sure it´s a unique KEY?? It looks like don´t

Comment: @Nacho, it comes from the mg_terms.term_id that is a unique table. In the the mg_brands, it is not a key. How to change the query so I can have the updated values?

Comment: this is the printout: CREATE TABLE `mg_brands` (
 `term_id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: And you primery key is?? The default autoincrement key. You need to set the term_id as UNIQUE KEY so the ON DUPLICATE will work. The problem it´s that now you don´t have any duplicate because you don´t have term_id as PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Ok let me check settings the term_id ad unique key.

Comment: @Nacho, it was that, setting term_id as unique key it works fine! many thanks at Solarflare too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the term_id as `UNIQUE KEY` so the `ON DUPLICATE` will work. The problem it´s that now you don´t have any duplicate because you don´t have term_id as `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: SOLVED - Indeed I was missing the UNIQUE KEY. As I selected it for the term_id, the query worked fine. Thanks for your help!